# Maintaining same class using delegation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, delegation

I'm trying to wrap my head around delegation vs. inheritance so I'm manually delegating a version of Array. One of the specific reasons I read to do this is because when you use things like enumerables, your returned value on the inherited methods reverts back to the parent class (i.e. Array). So I did this:

```
module PeepData
  # A list of Peeps
  class Peeps
    include Enumerable

    def initialize(list = [])
      @list = list
    end

    def [](index)
      @list[index]
    end

    def each(...)
      @list.each(...)
    end

    def reverse
      Peeps.new(@list.reverse)
    end

    def last
      @list.last
    end

    def join(...)
      @list.join(...)
    end

    def from_csv(csv_table)
      @list = []
      csv_table.each { |row| @list << Peep.new(row.to_h) }
    end

    def include(field, value)
      Peeps.new(select { |row| row[field] == value })
    end

    def exclude(field, value)
      Peeps.new(select { |row| row[field] != value })
    end

    def count_by_field(field)
      result = {}
      @list.each do |row|
        result[row[field]] = result[row[field]].to_i + 1
      end
      result
    end

    protected

    attr_reader :list
  end
end
```

When I instantiate this, my include and exclude function great and return a Peeps class but when using an enumerable like select, it returns Array, which prevents me from chaining further Peeps specific methods after the select. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid with learning about delegation.

```
p = Peeps.new
p.from_csv(csv_generated_array_of_hashes)
p.select(&:certified?).class
```

returns Array

If I override select, wrapping it in Peeps.new(), I get a "SystemStackError: stack level too deep". It seems to be recursively burying the list deeper into the list during the select enumeration.

```
def select(...)
  Peeps.new(@list.select(...))
end
```

Any help and THANKS!

Comment: Are these peeps the marshmallow variety?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that's possible, but it shouldn't matter if it's that, Little Bo's family, people in general or the verb form.

Comment: Anyone who has played with a marshmallow `Peep` before eating it knows that they are highly polymorphic.

Comment: I REALLY wanted to upvote these because they made me laugh but I'm not so sure they added anything strictly "useful" to the post LoL! Highly polymorphic (and pretty flammable) :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using both [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) and [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html).  Use Forwardable to delegate the `each` method to your list (to satisfy the Enumerable interface requirement), and also forward any [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html) methods you might want to include that are not part of the Enumerable module, such as `size`.  I would also suggest **not** overriding the behavior of `select` as it is supposed to return an array and would at the very least lead to confusion.  I would suggest something like the `subset` provided below to implement the behavior you are looking for.

```
require 'forwardable'

class Peeps
  include Enumerable
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :@list, :each, :size

  def initialize(list = [])
    @list = list
  end

  def subset(&block)
    selected = @list.select(&block)
    Peeps.new(selected)
  end
  
  protected
  attr_reader :list

end
```

Example usage:

```
peeps = Peeps.new([:a,:b,:c])
subset = peeps.subset {|s| s != :b}
puts subset.class 
peeps.each do |peep|
   puts peep
end
puts peeps.size
puts subset.size
```

produces:

```
Peeps
a
b
c
3
2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that if `Peeps#select` will return an `Array`, then it is OK to `include Enumerable`. But, you want `Peeps#select` to return a `Peeps`. I don't think you should `include Enumerable`. It's misleading to *claim* to be an `Enumerable` if you don't conform to its interface. This is just my opinion. There is no clear consensus on this in the ecosystem. See "Examples from the ecosystem" below.

If we accept that we cannot `include Enumerable`, here's the first implementation that comes to my mind.

```rb
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Peeps
  ARRAY_METHODS = %i[flat_map map reject select]
  ELEMENT_METHODS = %i[first include? last]

  def initialize(list)
    @list = list
  end

  def inspect
    @list.join(', ')
  end

  def method_missing(mth, *args, &block)
    if ARRAY_METHODS.include?(mth)
      self.class.new(@list.send(mth, *args, &block))
    elsif ELEMENT_METHODS.include?(mth)
      @list.send(mth, *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

class PeepsTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_first
    assert_equal('alice', Peeps.new(%w[alice bob charlie]).first)
  end

  def test_include?
    assert Peeps.new(%w[alice bob charlie]).include?('bob')
  end

  def test_select
    peeps = Peeps.new(%w[alice bob charlie]).select { |i| i < 'c' }
    assert_instance_of(Peeps, peeps)
    assert_equal('alice, bob', peeps.inspect)
  end
end
```

I don't normally use `method_missing`, but it seemed convenient.

### Examples from the ecosystem

There doesn't seem to be a consensus on how *strictly* to follow interfaces.

- `ActionController::Parameters` used to inherit `Hash`. Inheritance ceased in Rails 5.1.
- `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` still inherits `Hash`.

Comment: Same comment as above. Like a crash course in more advanced ruby that I needed.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answer, this isn't really proper usage of `Enumerable`. That said, you could still include `Enumerable` and use some meta-programming to override the methods that you want to be peep-chainable:

```
module PeepData
  class Peeps
    include Enumerable
 
    PEEP_CHAINABLES = [:map, :select]

    PEEP_CHAINABLES.each do |method_name|
      define_method(method_name) do |&block|
        self.class.new(super(&block))
      end
    end

    # solution for select without meta-programming looks like this:
    # def select
    #   Peeps.new(super)
    # end
  end
end
```

Just so you know, this really has nothing to do with inheritance vs delegation. If `Peeps` extended `Array`, you would have the exact same issue, and the exact solution above would still work.

Comment: Awesome stuff. A bunch to unpack for me learning wise and great point in the right direction.

Comment: Also you're right this isn't inheritance. I started there (inheriting from Array) then read several places not to do that for this kind of reason. At least one of the sites called what I'm doing here manual delegation but for the most part I'm not really using the Enumerable methods if I'm overriding select so it's not even delegation. I see your point.

Comment: Some feedback for @TonyArra : The solution without meta-programming is a beautiful touch. So often, rubyists are always showcasing their vast knowledge leading to answers that are very obscure to those of us at the more intermediate level of ruby understanding. Your answer not only provided the basic programming example but also bridged the gap to the more deeper understanding by bridging to meta-programming. It helped provide a new path for self learning. THANKS!